# Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"value1" | "value2" | undefined' (union type)

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I have a union type in Vue, which is optional (with the `?` character )

(**Edit**: forgot to rename "MyInterface" to Props)

```
interface Props{
    setting?: 'value1' | 'value2'
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
    setting: 'value1'
});
```

In the parent component, I pass downa variable set to a value that matches one of the union members:

```
    const setting = 'value1';
</script>

<template>

    <MyComponent :setting="setting" />
```

But the ":setting" property has the error:

```
 Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"value1" | "value2" | undefined'
```

If I would hardcode a string, the error goes away:

```
:setting="'value1'"
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your `interface` definition, You are assigning `'value1' | 'value2'` as a data type for a `setting` prop But if you see you are assigning a `string` type value in a component property. That's the reason it is giving you a syntax error.

It should be **:**

```
interface Props{
    setting?: string
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
    setting: 'value1'
});
```

Here is the official documentation [`link`](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#props-default-values) for more understanding.

Answer (score 0):

1. What is your `interface MyInterface`  for?
2. And where are the `<Props>` defined?

Shouldn't it be?

```
<script setup lang="ts">

export interface Props  {
    setting?: 'value1' | 'value2'
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
    setting: 'value1'
}); 

</script>
```

Here is the working [SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNplkMFOwzAMhl/FyqWbNC2CY5cWIbgi8QC5hOJCpDaJEneASt99adZ1XXeJbMv/5/x/z56d2x87ZDkTofLaEQSkzpXS6NZZT/D292JjZdAQ1N62kO35YjaKM2kqa0KSkjZfUEB2VE2Hj9lBGsHP4IiMDWHrGkUYOwCxhPMS7mb5RCwkmyrJzouCzyS2Y6sPrd1AoxKDgmTxMP4mZ9oQ+lpVCO/eugDQj/fh4uIpn1w8ZPA/G5JmuLh1SVXAj6bvV6xV11DYfGKtDSagSG+52e5W5Cs40raH5GbO6Daha6J9P9XDID48HzcXEQwn5UOhPQ==)

Comment: Sorry, that was a syntax error, I don't have that in my project (i updated the code now).
I still get the linting error though.
I can't see linting errors in your example (for example if I change it to const setting = 'value22'; there is no error..